# kendoui: Uncaught ReferenceError: uid is not defined

Tags: json, datagrid, kendo-ui

In my datagrid I read from database dumped in json using tornado server
It looks like this if api/notes visited:
`{"total": 0, "rows": "[]"}`
(table is empty initially, user supposed to fill it...)
And ofcourse dataSource is:

```
   transport: {
      read: {
        url: '/api/notes/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
      },


      parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
        var map = {};
        if (operation == 'read') {
            map.page = options.page;
            map.rows = options.take;
            map.sort = options.sort;
            if (map.sort) {
              map.sort = map.sort[0];
              if (map.sort) {
                var t = map.sort;
                map.sort = t.field;
                map.order = t.dir;
              }
            }
```

on page load i get Uncaught ReferenceError: uid is not defined

chrome dump:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: uid is not defined
(anonymous function)
h.extend._rowsHtmlkendo.web.min.js:10
h.extend.refreshkendo.web.min.js:10
e.extend.proxy.gjquery.min.js:2
B.extend.triggerkendo.web.min.js:10
o.extend._processkendo.web.min.js:10
o.extend.successkendo.web.min.js:10
e.extend.proxy.gjquery.min.js:2
p.extend.read.c.successkendo.web.min.js:10
f.Callbacks.njquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery.min.js:2
wjquery.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.djquery.min.js:4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I fed client with unparsed json
Wrapping data in json.loads() did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the [schema](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schema-object) of your data source:

```
schema: {
  total: "total",
  data: "rows"
}
```

Comment: Then you can try creating a live demo using jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net.